# Convert degrees-minutes-seconds coordinates to decimal degrees with untidy data

Tags: r, decimal, coordinates, spatial

I have the following dataset with untidy degrees-minutes-seconds coordinates in an Excel. I want to change them to decimal degrees coordinates.

```
Latitude              Longitude
40 39' 05''N          280 44' 31''E
40 34' 51''N            280 19' 35''E
80 81’ 31.54” N       270 36’ 39.87" E
90 20’ 15.62” N       270 12’ 18.05” E
80 45’ 2.45” N        270 21' 26.38" E
80 74' 82.00" N       270 44' 96" E
80 51’ 31.00” N       270 33’ 41’’ E
40 25’ 27.44’’N       320 31’ 54.85’’E
Lat: 40 27’ 35.62’’N    320 17’ 56.46’’E
40 43' 39''N            280 21' 34''E
```

The 0 of each term in Latitude and Longitude is supposed to be a Degree Symbol °.

Comment: The first challenge is obviously to “read” the degree-minute seconds.  It would be a lot easier if you had commas when exporting from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this three-step in base R:

```r
basic <- readLines("~/Downloads/qq")[-1] |>
  strcapture("(.*[NS]) *(.*[EW])", x = _, list(lat="", lon="")) 
basic
#                     lat              lon
# 1          40 39' 05''N    280 44' 31''E
# 2          40 34' 51''N    280 19' 35''E
# 3       80 81’ 31.54” N 270 36’ 39.87" E
# 4       90 20’ 15.62” N 270 12’ 18.05” E
# 5        80 45’ 2.45” N 270 21' 26.38" E
# 6       80 74' 82.00" N    270 44' 96" E
# 7       80 51’ 31.00” N   270 33’ 41’’ E
# 8       40 25’ 27.44’’N 320 31’ 54.85’’E
# 9  Lat: 40 27’ 35.62’’N 320 17’ 56.46’’E
# 10         40 43' 39''N    280 21' 34''E
```

```r
middle <- lapply(basic, function(X) t(sapply(regmatches(X, gregexpr("[0-9.]+", X)), as.numeric)))
middle
# $lat
#       [,1] [,2]  [,3]
#  [1,]   40   39  5.00
#  [2,]   40   34 51.00
#  [3,]   80   81 31.54
#  [4,]   90   20 15.62
#  [5,]   80   45  2.45
#  [6,]   80   74 82.00
#  [7,]   80   51 31.00
#  [8,]   40   25 27.44
#  [9,]   40   27 35.62
# [10,]   40   43 39.00
# $lon
#       [,1] [,2]  [,3]
#  [1,]  280   44 31.00
#  [2,]  280   19 35.00
#  [3,]  270   36 39.87
#  [4,]  270   12 18.05
#  [5,]  270   21 26.38
#  [6,]  270   44 96.00
#  [7,]  270   33 41.00
#  [8,]  320   31 54.85
#  [9,]  320   17 56.46
# [10,]  280   21 34.00
```

```r
final <- lapply(middle, function(Z) rowSums(Z / c(1, 60, 3600))) |>
  data.frame()
final
#          lat       lon
# 1  40.651389 280.74194
# 2  51.676111  39.67194
# 3  81.547889  36.73950
# 4  90.337672 270.20501
# 5   3.795833  30.88583
# 6  75.388889  45.67500
# 7  80.858611 270.56139
# 8  28.113611  60.19194
# 9  27.604778  18.02989
# 10 40.727500 280.35944
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pipeline

```
> openxlsx::read.xlsx('foo.xlsx') |>  ## read from .xlsx
+   sapply(gsub, pat='[^0-9. NSEW]', rep='') |> trimws() |>  ## delete unnecessary stuff
+   apply(2, strsplit, split='\\s|(?=\\w$)', perl=TRUE) |> ## split at space or indicator
+   lapply(simplify2array) |> lapply(t) |> lapply(as.data.frame) |>  ## transform format a little
+   lapply(type.convert, as.is=TRUE) |>  ## convert columns (numeric, character)
+   lapply(\(x) {  ## calculate decimal degrees
+     x[1:3] <- t(t(x[1:3])*c(1, 1/60, 1/60^2))
+     rowSums(x[1:3])*c(-1,1)[1L + grepl('N|E', x[[4]])]
+   }) |> as.data.frame()  ## make data.frame
   Latitude Longitude
1  4.651389  28.74194
2  4.580833  28.32639
3  9.358761  27.61107
4  9.337672  27.20501
5  8.750681  27.35733
6  9.256111  27.76000
7  8.858611  27.56139
8  4.424289  32.53190
9  4.459894  32.29902
10 4.727500  28.35944
```

---

*Data:*

```
> openxlsx::read.xlsx('foo.xlsx')  |> dput()
structure(list(Latitude = c("4° 39' 05''N     ", "4° 34' 51''N     ", 
"8° 81’ 31.54” N  ", "9° 20’ 15.62” N  ", "8° 45’ 2.45” N   ", 
"8° 74' 82.00\" N  ", "8° 51’ 31.00” N  ", "4° 25’ 27.44’’N  ", 
"Lat: 4° 27’ 35.62’’N ", "4° 43' 39''N      "), Longitude = c("28° 44' 31''E", 
"28° 19' 35''E", "27° 36’ 39.87\" E", "27° 12’ 18.05” E", 
"27° 21' 26.38\" E", "27° 44' 96\" E", "27° 33’ 41’’ E", 
"32° 31’ 54.85’’E", "32° 17’ 56.46’’E", "28° 21' 34''E"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I am having this error message: Error in t(x[1:3]) * c(1, 1/60, 1/60^2) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
Maybe is because of another example that is different.

Comment: @Paula Sounds like the `gsub` didn't remove all non-numeric stuff. Did you check what comes out of the pipes individually whether it looks right, i.e. running the code just before each of the `|>` pipes?